# Break from an imported function in main(), python

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python and to practice what I've learned, I'm working on a console RPG game.

The way I want to do it is like this:

- I have a main file called main.py where the `main()` function is inside.
- I have other files for other systems like the combat system, the levelling system etc..

What I want to do is to import the combatsys.py (that contains the function of the combat system of the game) inside my main.py, which wasn't a problem.

My problem is that I call the function of combatsys.py inside a while loop in main.py. But I want the loop to break when a condition inside combatsys.py becomes true. I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here's a snippet of the main.py file:

```py
from levelsys import level_system
from combatsys import combat_system

character = {

"name": "",
"level": 1,
"experience" : 0,
"next level": 10,
"Health Points": 10,
"Max HP": 10,
"Gold": 0,
"stats": {
            "Strength" : 1,
            "Defense"  : 1,
            "Intelligence": 1
         }
}

enemy = {

"name": "Zombie",
"level": 1,
"experience" : 0,
"next level": 10,
"Health Points": 10,
"Max HP": 10,
"stats": {
            "Strength" : 1,
            "Defense"  : 1,
            "Intelligence": 1
         }
}




def main():
    temp = 0
    print("You are being attacked by a", enemy["name"],".")
    print("How will you respond to that?")
    print("1-) Attack.")
    print("2-) Defend.")
    print("3-) Run.")
    choice = input("--> ")
    
    while character["Health Points"] >= 0 or enemy["Health Points"] >= 0:
       
        combat_system(character, choice, enemy, temp)
        

        print("1-) Attack.")
        print("2-) Defend.")
        print("3-) Run.")
        choice = input("--> ")

    level_system(character)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("#################################################")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#                    MY GAME                    #")
    print("#           Journey to learning Python          #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#                               By : Godspeed   #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#            <Press ENTER to continue>          #")
    print("#                                               #")
    print("#################################################")

    input()

    print("Welcome stranger. What's your name?")
    character["name"] = input("--> ")
    
    # print("Input the experience to add  in order to test:")
    # character["experience"] = int(input("--> "))
    main()
```

And here's a snippet of the combatsys.py file:

```py
import random

def combat_system(character, choice, enemy, temp):

    # If Player attacks Enemy:

    if choice.lower().strip() == "attack":

        print("You chose to attack the enemy.")
    
        # Calculating the ATK DMG:

        attack_damage = (random.randint(0, int(character["stats"]["Strength"]))) - (random.randint(0, int((enemy["stats"]["Defense"] / 2))))

        print("The damage you inflicted is: ", attack_damage )

        # Calculating new HP:

        enemy["Health Points"] -= attack_damage

        # When enemy dies:

        if enemy["Health Points"] <= 0:
            print("The enemy's current HP is: ", 0)
            print("You were able to kill the enemy. Good work.")
            enemy["Health Points"] = enemy["Max HP"]

            # Gaining XP when killing the enemy:
            character["experience"] += random.randint(0, (character["next level"]/2))
            print("Congratulations. You gained ", character["experience"], "experience.")
            print()
            temp = 1
        else:
            print("The enemy's current HP is: ", enemy["Health Points"]) 
        print()
        
        # When Enemy attacks player: 

        attack_damage = (random.randint(0, int(enemy["stats"]["Strength"]))) - (random.randint(0, int((character["stats"]["Defense"] / 2))))
        print()
        print("You got attacked by a", enemy["name"])
        print("The damage inflicted by", enemy["name"], "is:", attack_damage )


        character["Health Points"] -= attack_damage

        # When player dies:

        if character["Health Points"] <= 0:
            print("Your current HP is: ", 0)
            print("You have been killed by the enemy. Game Over")
            character["Health Points"] = character["Max HP"]
            print()
            temp = 1
        else:    
            print("Your new HP is: ", character["Health Points"])
```

Comment: The way you did it seems to be fine (you are passing a dict which is mutable, the function changes it, and then you check its values in the `while`). What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: `while character["Health Points"] >= 0 or enemy["Health Points"] >= 0` Think about what the `or` means in that condition.

Comment: Also you are doing `character["Health Points"] = character["Max HP"]` whenever the user's health gets to 0. So the loop will never finish. You "revive" the user whenever they get killed...

Comment: You should have `combat_system` return information that you need in main to determine if you should break or not

Comment: I believe the issue is the `or` as slothrop mentioned, but if you want to be able to get data from other modules you can do something like `import combatsys` and then check its attributes you set in it, such as `combatsys.some_flag = True` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly which variable you want to check.
But you can return a boolean at the end of your `combat_system()` function to tell your main.py file whether to break the loop or not.

For example you can have a variable as flag in your `combat_system()`, set it `True` when the condition happens, and return it at the end of your `combat_system()` to tell your `main.py` file to break the loop. Then you can add this change to your loop in `main.py` :

```py
# Run the function and store the result boolean value
exit_loop = combat_system(character, choice, enemy, temp)
# Check if the condition is happened
if (exit_loop):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sudo example. You can maintain a state flag or many state flags in the imported function and let the main function react based on the flag. So when the flag variable will be set to let say `False` you can break out of the loop. Just a conceptual example:

```py
import random
import time


def play(health: int):
    health_gain_loss = random.randint(-20, 15)
    playable_status = True
    health_after = health + health_gain_loss
    if health_after < 50:
        playable_status = False
    if health_gain_loss > 0:
        print(f"Got health during play +{health_gain_loss}. Total health {health_after}")
    else:
        print(f"Got health during play {health_gain_loss}. Total health {health_after}")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
    return health_after, playable_status


def main():
    health = 70
    steps = 1
    while steps <= 20:
        steps += 1
        print(f"Playing for {steps} iteration.")
        health, playable = play(health)
        if not playable:
            print("===== Game Lost ====")
            break
    if steps == 20:
        print("++++ Game Won ++++")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here I am initializing a game with health 70 and the game can be won if the game can run until 20 iteration and players health is `>50`. During the 20 steps if players health goes under 50 the while loop will be closed and the game will be lost.